# PDF metadata not captured when file is saved sharepoint application

Tags: metadata

I have a document library in sharepoint site and it contain pdf documents. Documents has 10 metadata including document number. Document number is auto generate unique ID for each file. When i save the pdf in my local I see that pdf does not capture the metadata filled. I want to re-use those metadata when re-uploading somewhere else. This metadata get captured for word document but not for pdf. Can someone help me with that how i can acheive this either by c# or javascript of some OOB feature. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a function of SharePoint that it recognises MS-Word as a file format it knows how to embed meta-data in. It does not know how to do this for PDF files.

What you can do (using code or a third party product) is to embed the meta-data in the PDF as a watermark. (Disclaimer, I work for a company that makes such as product)

You can also take it much further and use event receivers or workflows (and a lot of code) to embed the meta data inside the PDF (XMP meta data) whenever the meta data or PDF file is updated. When the file is then uploaded elsewhere you can copy the meta data back.

Comment: can you provide any such event receiver as example. Thanks

Comment: I have no example, but Google for 'Creating a SharePoint Event Receiver' and 'Editing XMP meta data using C#' and combine what you find.